# « Épisode », « phase », « cycle »ou « état d’esprit »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Quel est le terme le plus pertinent parmi « épisode », « phase », « cycle » et « état d’esprit » dans la phrase (selon le contexte) ci-après.

> Il est encore dans l’**épisode** « je passe toutes mes soirées de semaine en boîte de nuit, allant d’aventure en aventure, essuyant du même coup déception sur déception.

> Il est encore dans sa **phase** « je passe toutes mes soirées de semaine en boîte de nuit, allant d’aventure en aventure, essuyant du même coup déception sur déception.

> Il est encore dans son **cycle** « je passe toutes mes soirées de semaine en boîte de nuit, allant d’aventure en aventure, essuyant du même coup déception sur déception.

> Il est encore dans son **état d’esprit** « je passe toutes mes soirées de semaine en boîte de nuit, allant d’aventure en aventure, essuyant du même coup déception sur déception.

Bien évidemment, si vous jugez qu’aucune des propositions n’est convenable, vous avez mon autorisation ou plutôt la liberté (voyons) de penser l’idée différemment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le mieux adapté me semble:
**il est encore dans sa phase...**.
Le *encore* indique une durée limitée confirmant une *phase*.

*Épisode*, unitaire, ne va pas bien avec la répétition de tous les soirs. A la rigueur, on dirait 'il est encore dans **un** épisode **du genre** ”je passe ...".

*Cycle* indiquerait qu'il a déjà fait ça et que ça recommence...par cycles. D'ailleurs on dirait
'il est encore dans **un** de **ses cycles** "je passe...". Le *encore* ici n'indique plus une longueur comme pour phase, mais une répétition.

Enfin *un état d'esprit* n'est pas réservé à cet individu et ne suppose pas qu'on agisse. On dirait plutôt :
il est encore dans **un** état d'esprit: "je **passerais** bien toutes mes soirées..."

Comment: Hormis ces termes, lesquels auriez-vous employés pour donner corps à cette idée? Pourriez-vous penser la phrase par vous-même, dans vos propres mots,  sans faire référence aux formulations présentées, comme si vous ne les aviez jamais lues? Les corrections que vous avez apportées à mes phrases me satisfont, je vous en remercie.

Comment: En fait, j'aimerais bien qu'on me présente d'autres façons de tourner cette phrase dans un registre courant ou littéraire.

Comment: Un essai :      Passer son temps à fréquenter les boîtes de nuit et à collectionner les aventures ne peut que le mener de déception en déception, comme il le prouve en ce moment.